# Python matplotlib graph, show empty graph

Tags: python, physics

I don't seem to find problem why graph is not showing any lines, its just blank. I am new to python.
"Trying to plot graph maximum height and range with angle"

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def projectile(Vo,Angle):
   Acc=9.8
   Mheight=(Vo**2)*np.sin(np.radians(Angle**2))/Acc**2
   Range=(Vo**2)*(np.sin(np.radians(Angle)))/Acc
   plt.plot(int(Mheight),int(Angle)) // This is the line
   plt.show()  // only showing blank graph
   return ("Maximum Height: ",Mheight,"Maximum Range: ",Range)

#Main Function  
Vo=int(input("Enter Velocity: "))
Angle=int(input("Enter Angle: "))
print(projectile(Vo,Angle))
```

Comment: plt.plot(list_of_xs, list_of_ys) will draw a curve for you. You are plotting a single data point and thus don't see it. Use plt.scatter(...) instead and you will see the point being plotted.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should give plt.plot() a tuple object.

thus, like:

```
    plt.plot((int(Mheight),int(Angle)))
    plt.show()
```

by the way, remember the typesetting of your code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).